# On entry to DGEEV parameter number 9 had an illegal value

Tags: c, lapack, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying for the first time to use LAPACK from C to diagonalize a matrix and I am stuck.

I have been trying to modify this example http://rcabreral.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/eigenvalues-clapack.html from `zgeev` to `dgeev`. I have looked at the `DGEEV` input parameters, http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d28/dgeev_8f.html but it seems I don't understand the well enough.

Hence, the code below produces:

> **** On entry to DGEEV parameter number  9 had an illegal value**

**EDIT:** The error occurs in the call of `dgeev` spanning lines 48 to (including) 53.

**EDIT:** Note that the arguments differ from the specifications here
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d28/dgeev_8f.html
in that they have been translated to pointers. That is necessary when using these Fortran routines in C, as explained here:
http://www.physics.orst.edu/~rubin/nacphy/lapack/cprogp.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>    
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//.........................................................................

void dgeTranspose( double *Transposed, double *M ,int n) {    
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      Transposed[i+n*j] = M[i*n+j];
}
//.........................................................................
//  MatrixComplexEigensystem: computes the eigenvectors and eigenValues of input matrix A
//  The eigenvectors are stored in columns
//.........................................................................
void MatrixComplexEigensystem( double *eigenvectorsVR, double *eigenvaluesW, double *A, int N){
  int i;
  double *AT = (double *) malloc( N*N*sizeof(double ) );

  dgeTranspose( AT, A , N);

  char JOBVL ='N';   // Compute Right eigenvectors
  char JOBVR ='V';   // Do not compute Left eigenvectors
  double VL[1];

  int LDVL = 1;
  int LDVR = N;
  int LWORK = 4*N; 

  double *WORK =  (double *)malloc( LWORK*sizeof(double));
  double *RWORK = (double *)malloc( 2*N*sizeof(double));
  int INFO;

  dgeev_( &JOBVL, &JOBVR, &N, AT ,  &N , eigenvaluesW ,   
       VL, &LDVL,
       eigenvectorsVR, &LDVR, 
       WORK, 
       &LWORK, RWORK, &INFO );

  dgeTranspose( AT, eigenvectorsVR , N);

  for(i=0;i<N*N;i++) eigenvectorsVR[i]=AT[i];

  free(WORK);
  free(RWORK);
  free(AT);
}

int main(){
  int i,j;
  const int N = 3;
  double A[] = { 1.+I , 2. ,  3 , 4. , 5.+I , 6. , 7., 8., 9. + I};
  double eigenVectors[N*N];
  double eigenValues[N];

  MatrixComplexEigensystem( eigenVectors, eigenValues, A, N);

  printf("\nEigenvectors\n");
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++) printf("%e", eigenVectors[i*N + j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\nEigenvalues \n");
  for(i=0;i<N;i++) printf("%e",  eigenValues[i] );
  printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------\n"); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line in the code produced that message?

Comment: @WeatherVane It does not say. It just says 

ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ gcc -o mamapack mamapack.c -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -lblas && ./mamapack
 ** On entry to DGEEV parameter number  9 had an illegal value
ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$

Comment: If you use a debugger, or insert strategic self-bugging `printf` instructions, you can discover that with the Divide and Conquer method, which is similar in idea to a binary search.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you! It happens in the call of degeev spanning lines 48 to 53. I put a "strategic printf ping" in line 47 and one in line 54...

Comment: Parameter #9 (1-based) is `eigenvectorsVR`, which comes from the function argument `double *eigenvectorsVR`. Since we don't know anything about `dgeev_`, you are either passing an illegal pointer, or passing the pointer when you should be passing its value, or passing a pointer to an uninitialised array, or since this is a 2-D array, perhaps `dgeev_` is expecting a `**` pointer. The function that calls this, `MatrixComplexEigensystem`, is itself passed two uninitialised arrays, one initialised array and a size. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not port directly from `zgeev` to `dgeev`. The `zgeev` gets a complex matrix and computes complex eigenvalues. While `dgeev` gets a real matrix and computes complex eigenvalues. In order to be consistent `LAPACK` uses  `WR` and `WI` which is used for the real and imaginary part of each eigenvalue.

So note that `dgeev` definition is

> void dgeev_(char* JOBVL, char* JOBVR, int* N, double* A, int* LDA, double* WR, double* WI, double* VL, int* LDVL, double* VR, int* LDVR, double* WORK, int* LWORK, int* INFO);

My suggestion for your example is to remove:

```
#include <complex.h>
```

remove `I`'s from matrix of doubles:

```
double A[] = { 1. , 2. ,  3 , 4. , 5. , 6. , 7., 8., 9.};
```

then double the size of eigenvalues vector:

```
double eigenValues[2*N];
```

and call `dgeev` using `WR` and `WI`:

```
double *eigenvaluesWR = eigenvaluesW;
double *eigenvaluesWI = eigenvaluesW+N;
dgeev_(&JOBVL, &JOBVR, &N, AT, &N, 
    eigenvaluesWR, eigenvaluesWI, 
    VL, &LDVL, 
    eigenvectorsVR, &LDVR,
    WORK, &LWORK, &INFO);
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why the original author transposes the matrix?

Comment: @user1816316 this is the usual problem of 2D matrices exchange between `C` and `Fortran`. The `C` users store the matrices in RowMajor format. The `dgeev_` calls the `Fortran` subroutine which uses the ColumnMajor format storage. So transposing the matrix will convert it from RowMajor to ColumnMajor.